# Problem with SPARQL query

Tags: c#, .net, sparql

I have the following query that is not working:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema%23>
PREFIX i: <http://evolizer.org/ontologies/seon/2010/09/softwaremetrics.owl%23>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns%23>
SELECT ?metric ?value
WHERE {
?metric rdf:type i:SoftwareDesignMetric .
?metric i:hasName "NOM" .
?metric i:hasValue ?value 
?metric i:isMetricOf "http://130.60.156.155:8080/famixParser/projects/argouml/org.argouml.pattern.cognitive" .}
```

I used a [query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html) that throws the following exception:

```
Encountered "  "?metric "" at line 9, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    "graph" ...
    "optional" ...
    "service" ...
    "minus" ...
    "filter" ...
    "{" ...
    "}" ...
    ";" ...
    "," ...
    "." ...
```

But i don't know what that means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to add a period `.` after the graph pattern `?metric i:hasValue ?value` .

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. However I have an additional question. With the query validator I can validate a query, but is there also a web browser based tool to execute such a query?

Comment: Also http://www.dotnetrdf.org/demos/leviathan/ and http://sparql.org/sparql.html (which is a general purpose query processor at the same site you mention in your post).  Additionally if you just want to validate a query use any public endpoint and add LIMIT 0 to the end of the query - this will mean that the endpoint doesn't have to do any work to process the query (provided it is properly optimised) - but has to parse the query anyway.  Just use the endpoint as a validator, this is especially useful if you find an endpoint that gives good error messages.